Using `\babelfont` with `newtx` for multilingual typesetting
I'm writing my thesis in English (american) and use, amongst others, babel. For the font, it seems that the best/easiest way to use "Times New Roman" for both text and maths is the newtx package. As I want to display a few rare words in ancient Greek, I'm relying on babel's \babelfont and \foreignlanguage commands.
However, I've run into the following issue (compiling with LuaLaTeX).
When \babelfont is set for Greek, but not for the main font, babel gives a (long) warning about certain families using default settings:
Package babel: The following font families will use the default
(babel) settings for all or some languages:
(babel) * \rmfamily = TeXGyreTermesX(0)
(babel) [TeXGyreTermesX-Regular.otf]:mode=base;script=latn;language=dflt;-ss05;+tlig;+tnum;+lnum;
(babel) * \sffamily = lmss
(babel) [lmsans10-regular]:+tlig;
(babel) * \ttfamily = lmtt
(babel) [lmmono10-regular]:
(babel) There is nothing intrinsically wrong with it, but
(babel) 'babel' will no set Script and Language, which could
(babel) be relevant in some languages. If your document uses
(babel) these families, consider redefining them with \babelfont.
(babel) Reported.

However, if I do set a default \babelfont to TeXGyreTermesX, the font used by newtx, while the warning for \rmfamily does disappear, the font seems to be loaded without some settings and small caps, in particular, cannot be found any more:
LaTeX Font: Font shape `TU/TeXGyreTermesX(0)/m/sc' undefined
(Font)  using `TU/TeXGyreTermesX(0)/m/n' instead.

Here's the MWE:
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{newtx}
\babelfont[*greek]{rm}{tempora}
\babelfont{rm}{TeXGyreTermesX} % <-- the problematic line

\begin{document}
This is a test.
\textrm{This is a test.}
\textsc{This is a test.}
\texttt{This is a test.}
\textsf{This is a test.}
Now with some math: $E = mc^2$
\foreignlanguage{polytonicgreek}{κυβερνήτης}
\end{document}

My questions:

Is there a way to silence babel's warnings relating to fonts?
What is the best practice when using a "font package" such as newtx alongside babel?
Indirectly related: why isn't sf changed by newtx to a Helvetica clone?


With the package option silent, babel prints nothing.
